On self-consistent estimators of survival functions. How do they work?
I'm reading about how the estimation of the survival function is "self-consistent" because as Efron showed, we can estimate the survival function in the presence of right censoring as
$$
\hat{S}(t) = \frac{1}{n} \left[\text{Number of Alive at }t + \underset{\text{Est. no. of survivors on censored observations}}{ \sum_{T_i<t, \delta_i=0} \frac{\hat{S}(t)}{\hat{S}(T_i)}} \right]
$$
where we use an initial guess/estimate of $\hat{S}(t)$ to iteratively re-estimate $\hat{S}(t)$, and that this will converge to the Kaplan-Meier estimator. Turnbull then uses the same technique to extend the process to other censoring/truncation scenarios.I wanted to understand how and why this iterative process works.
But the book I'm reading (Klein & Moeschberger) does not go into detail (only mentions self-consistency and EM algorithm), while reading the original Efron and Turnbull papers are too hard for me. This paper on the EM algorithm by Dempster, Laird, and Rubin says that Efron used the EM algorithm, but I don't see the EM algorithm in the Efron and Turnbull papers, and they don't seem carry out the EM algorithm, so I'm also confused on this regard.
Ultimately, I wanted to understand why using the iterative self-consistent formula work? And are they equivalent to using the EM algorithm? I'd appreciate any explanation, hint, or easier readings about this (or if I it's worth powering through the original papers).

The self-consistency argument is as follows. As we go through time, we get to see the number of deaths $d_t$ out of people under observation $r_t$ at each time point.  We also have at any time $t$ a number of censored people whose death time we don't know. However, the non-informative censoring assumption says the same fraction $d_t/r_t$ of these unobserved people die at time $t$.
So, if we have a starting estimator $\hat S(t)$, eg, the empirical CDF of thd deaths, we can use this estimator to assign death proportions at each time for all the censored people to get a new estimate $\hat S_1(t)$.  We can then use this estimator to assign revised death proportions at each time for the censored people to get a new estimate $\hat S_2(t)$, and so on.
This algorithm makes no reference to maximisation of anything.
You could alternatively say that you want to define $\hat S$ as a non-parametric maximum likelihood estimator, maximising a likelihood that is $p_t$ for a person dying at time $t$ and $S(t)$ for a person censored at time $t$ (and so dying some time in the future).  Given that likelihood, you could maximise it using your favourite optimisation algorithm.  Or, you could try to develop an EM scheme for it.  One possible EM scheme is exactly the self-consistency algorithm, where the M step is forming the empirical CDF and the E step is distribution censored observations over all the event times after they are censored.
It is an interesting (and a priori not obvious) fact that the lifetable product-limit approach of Kaplan and Meier, the self-consistency approach, and non-parametric maximum likelihood all give the same estimator.

Thank you very much! This clarified how the approaches connect. I was able to verify for myself that the NPML, product-limit, and self-consistency approaches give the same estimators, although I'm not yet sure I understand the bit about EM algorithm. I did the redistribution to the right algorithm, and ended up with the same estimates. However, I cannot understand why it is equal to an EM approach where we compute an expectation of a log-likelihood. If you don't mind a follow up question, can you expand on the bit about the EM approach? I've marked this solved nonetheless. Thank you again!
